# Symfony 3 custom input in login form

Tags: php, symfony

I have simple login form in Symfony 3

```
namespace ForumBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    $authUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

    $loginError = $authUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    $lastLogin = $authUtils->getLastUsername();

    var_dump($request->request);

    return $this->render('ForumBundle:Default:login.html.twig', array(
        'last_username' => $lastLogin,
        'login_error' => $loginError,
    ));
  }
}
```

and view

```
{% if login_error %}
{{ login_error.messageKey }}
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path('forum_login') }}" method="post">
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}">
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="_password">
<input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="{{ path('forum_admin') }}">
<button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

I would like to have custom field in form and in SecurityController can access it. Is it possible?

Comment: What stop you to add another input field?

Comment: It's not problem but how read new input in php?

Comment: In php you have `$_POST` global variable, in symfony you have `$request->request->get('custom_field');` but better use form component instead of raw html forms.

Comment: That won't work the form is handled at `login_check` route, so parameters do not exist anymore in the `SecurityController` (`login` route), that's why there is the `security.authentication_utils` for retrieving data.

Comment: So is it any solution?

Comment: What field do you want to add and what are you going to use it for? Knowing that may help provider possible solutions

Comment: For example session time. I learn symfony and i would like to know if i can add some inputs.